# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory при сохранении файла в папке OneDrive

Tags: python, python-3.x, onedrive

Я получаю сообщение об ошибке при попытке сохранить данные в файл, если все находится в папке OneDrive. Если переместить все в другое место, все будет сохранено, например:

> C:\Users\max\OneDrive\Documents\ - ошибка

> C:\Users\max\OneDrive\ - нет ошибки

Результат такой же при запуске от администратора или выключении OneDrive. Папка сохранена локально (она существует, ее можно увидеть при выводе)

```py
with open("hello.txt", "w") as file:
    print("Hello world", file=file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как выяснилось, проблема была в Windows defender. Если у кого-то подобная проблема попробуйте: Защита от вирусов и угроз - Параметры защиты от вирусов и других угроз - Контролируемый доступ к папкам - Выключить нафиг.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не рассматривали виртуальное пространство использовать